# Android : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' exit with non-Zero Value 1

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-maps-api-2

Am getting error when I rebuild the project. After I add the dependency for the  google Map V2 this error occur.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:  org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
```

Process 'command 'C:\Users\Binil\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I tried to clean the project and rebuild the project but same issue occur again. Also I try sync the project but not solved

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

When I remove this dependency then app build successfully.

**Gradle.build**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android4dev.navigationview"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this with-in android tag to your module build.gradle:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Also, if you only want to use maps try to add this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
```

Instead of

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **apply plugin** com.google.gms.google-services after dependencies

```
dependencies 
{    
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```